# LWC Passing List Parameters to Apex Controller

Tags: salesforce, lwc

How to pass List data type from  LWC @wire method to Custom Aura Method

Comment: To Apex or to another Aura controller? Your question is unclear. What have you tried so far, post some code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by making an array of required datatype:

If your data type is of primitive type than push that directly into the array, or

If your data type is an object or subject, create a javascript object by making use of {},
add the key values corresponding to the object structure, and push the same in the array.

At last, leverage the same array to pass it to the apex controller method.

Answer (score 0):

Let say you have an Apex class as below

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static Object processResponse(string recordId) { }
```

Below is the example wire statement to call the above method and passing the recordId.

```
@wire(processResponse, { recordId: '123123123' })
contact;
```